# How to hide floatingActionButton when endDrawer is open Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have two drawers, left and right drawers. I am able to hide the floatingButton on scroll. I want to hide the floating Button on pulling the endDrawer or when the endDrawer is open through a click in one of the menu items in the AppBar. I have failed to figure out the controlers to be used. Anyone with sample working code - Help.

```
    child: Scaffold(
    primary: true,
    key: _globalKey,
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    extendBody: true,
    floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
    //bottomNavigationBar: bottomFABBottonAppBar(),
    floatingActionButton: floatinActionButton(),
    appBar: appBarVisibility
        ? actionBar()
        : PreferredSize(
            child: Container(),
            preferredSize: Size(0.0, 0.0),
          ),
    drawer: MainNavigationDrawer(),
    body: Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        endDrawer: FilterEndDrawer(),
        body: singleScrollView()),
  ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you have the end drawer in the child `Scaffold`, so the `FloatingActionButton` is above the child `Scaffold` including its endDrawer.

try moving the endDrawer to the parent `Scaffold`

```
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  appBar: AppBar(),
  floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(),
  drawer: Drawer(),
  endDrawer: Drawer(),
  body: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: Container(
    ),
  ),
);
```

or move the `FloatingActionButton` to the child `Scaffold`

```
child: Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  appBar: AppBar(),
  drawer: Drawer(),
  body: Scaffold(
    floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(),
    appBar: AppBar(),
    endDrawer: Drawer(),
    body: Container(
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: The second solution was a perfect answer to what exactly I was looking at. The left right drawer is above the appBar and above the floating button, while the right left endDrawer is below the app bar and above the floating button.  Thank you @Elfor - Simple but perfect answer.